# Scripting Issue with JMeter for Cognito applications

Tags: jmeter-4.0

I am facing some problem while doing the load testing with Cognito based applications using JMeter. While capturing the request I have observed that "PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE" parameter which is added by AWS SDK. It is impossible to capture it before that request as it is passed in that request. The particular request is failing. I am blocking to create the script. Did anyone work successfully on similar things which can help me?